# Simple python tkinter dice roll game

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple dice simulator with tkinter but keep running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\NetBeansProjects\DiceSIMULATOR\src\dicesimulator.py", line 18, in      <module>
    Label("Enter your guess").pack()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2573, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2084, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2062, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Here is my code:

```
from random import randrange
from tkinter import *


def checkAnswer():
    dice = randrange(1,7)
    if int(guess) == dice:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Well Done!","Correct!")
    if int(guess) > 6:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error"," Invalid number: try again")
    elif int(guess) <= 0:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error"," Invalid number: try again")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Incorrect","Incorrect: dice rolled {}.".format(diceRoll))

root = Tk()

Label("Enter your guess").pack()

g = StringVar()
inputGuess = TextBox(master, textvariable=v).pack()
guess = v.get()

submit = Button("Roll Dice", command = checkAnswer).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the modified version of your code:

The `Label` widget needs a parent (in this case, it's `root`). You didn't specify that. The same applies for the `Button` widget. Second, the variable `v` is undefined, but I think you meant `g`, so change all references to the variable `v` to `g`.

```
from random import randrange
from tkinter import *


def checkAnswer():
    dice = randrange(1,7)
    if int(guess) == dice:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Well Done!","Correct!")
    if int(guess) > 6:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error"," Invalid number: try again")
    elif int(guess) <= 0:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error"," Invalid number: try again")
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Incorrect","Incorrect: dice rolled {}.".format(diceRoll))

root = Tk()

Label(root,text="Enter your guess").pack() #parent wasn't specified, added root

g = StringVar() 
inputGuess = Entry(root, textvariable=g).pack() #changed variable from v to g
guess = g.get() #changed variable from v to g

submit = Button(root, text = "Roll Dice", command = checkAnswer).pack() #added root as parent
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The parent wasn't specified for the `Label` widget.

Comment: Don't just dump code, do explain what the OP got wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, completely forgot about v

Comment: I corrected the code but still getting:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\NetBeansProjects\DiceSIMULATOR\src\dicesimulator.py", line 18, in <module>
    Label(root,"Enter your guess").pack()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2573, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2087, in __init__
    classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @joyalrj22 How about I go over it with you at CPC on Tuesday? lol :)

Comment: @joyalrj22, you should specify the `text` option i.e. `text = "Enter your guess"`. So, replace Line 18 with `Label(root,text="Enter your guess").pack()`